# Page frames in Operating Systems

Tags: operating-system

Why given 16-bit virtual addresses and 32KB physical memmory, if you take a page frame to be 4KB why then is the mapping 0-4K, 4K-8K etc.? Given 16-bit addresses why can you write 64KB programs?

As far as I know 4KB = 4 * 1024 bytes = 4 * 1024 * 8 bits = 32768 bits.
Somehow it doesn't check out?

Like Tannenbaum takes 0-4K addresses and this is supposed to be 4KB page frame which doesn't make sense? Thanks.

Thanks.

Comment: A 16-bit address doesn't refer to individual bits (unless the architecture has 1-bit bytes for some reason) it refers to a byte. So you can address 65536 different bytes, or 64KB.

Answer (score 1):

I understand your confusion, given 16 bits, you can address `2^16` different addresses. Each of these addresses is of size 1 byte.

Lets consider a system with 2 bits of virtual space.

```
   ___________
00 | 1 byte  |
01 | 1 byte  |
10 | 1 byte  |
11 | 1 byte  |
   -----------
```

You have 2^2 different addresses each of size byte. So your total virtual space is 4 bytes and not 4 bits.